# Send php value with jQuery ajax function to php function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have an ajax form that filters posts based on the category.
Setup:

1. HTML form
2. PHP function to echo ouput
3. jQuery ajax request to load php
   function

**Question:** How can I parse a value to the php function ($test, see below) from within the jQuery ajax function?

**Form - Outputs html select field and button to filter posts**

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url() ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" method="POST" id="filter">
    <?php
        if( $terms = get_terms( 'category', 'orderby=name' ) ) : // to make it simple I use default categories
            echo '<select name="categoryfilter"><option>Select category...</option>';
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) :
                echo '<option value="' . $term->term_id . '">' . $term->name . '</option>'; // ID of the category as the value of an option
            endforeach;
            echo '</select>';
        endif;
    ?>
        <button>Apply filter</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="myfilter">
</form>
<div id="response"></div>
```

**PHP function - Outputs result on button click in HTML form**

```
function misha_filter_function($test){

// Do something with $test, but how to parse it with jQuery into this php function?     

$args = array(
            'orderby' => 'date', // we will sort posts by date
            'order' => $_POST['date'] // ASC или DESC
        );

        // for taxonomies / categories
        if( isset( $_POST['categoryfilter'] ) )
            $args['tax_query'] = array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'category',
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'terms' => $_POST['categoryfilter']
                )
            );

        $query = new WP_Query( $args );

        if( $query->have_posts() ) :
            while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();
                echo '<h2>' . $query->post->post_title . '</h2>';
            endwhile;
            wp_reset_postdata();
        else :
            echo 'No posts found';
        endif;

        die();
    }


    add_action('wp_ajax_myfilter', 'misha_filter_function');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_myfilter', 'misha_filter_function');
```

**jQuery - Question: how to parse php value $test to the above php function?**

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('#filter').submit(function(){
        var filter = $('#filter');
        $.ajax({
            url:filter.attr('action'),
            data:filter.serialize(), // form data
            type:filter.attr('method'), // POST
            beforeSend:function(xhr){
                filter.find('button').text('Processing...'); // changing the button label
            },
            success:function(data){
                filter.find('button').text('Apply filter'); // changing the button label back
                $('#response').html(data); // insert data
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You serialize data so accesed by:

`parse_str($_POST['data'], $inputValues); //$inputValues will be array with your form fields`

Comment: Thanks. Can you help me a bit more by using / altering my code?

Comment: Just rewrite code to use $inputValues:


`$inputValues = array();
parse_str($_POST['data'], $inputValues);

if( isset( $inputValues['categoryfilter'] ) )`

Comment: Ok and how can I send the value to the php function with jQuery? So how to change the jQuery function that it sends the data?

Comment: @Bob you already sent data from jQuery to php script - using $.ajax(). Now you can get this data in php function directly from $_POST.